# Can’t access some webpages

Tags: ipad, safari, youtube, google, websites

When I go to certain websites, it says “safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server”
Screen time is currently not blocking any websites, and this happens with YouTube.com, docs.google.com and some other google related websites. The YouTube app still works. I am using an iPad Air 2

Comment: Does it happen in all WLANs you connect to, or only in specific ones? Did you clear browser cache, cookies etc and try again?

Comment: What is a WLAN?

Comment: A wireless network. The thing your iPad needs to connect to the Internet (unless it‘s a cellular model which also uses the cellular network)

Comment: Can you add some details about the networks this happens in, and if it happens in all of the networks you connect to? Also what have you tried so far (see also my comment from Feb 19th)?

Comment: This error is still going on, but still no answer or solution.  After several months